# I have a problem with pushing my bot files to heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I want to push my bot to heroku (used TechWithTim's tut) and don't know why it don't works...

i'm a begginer but i tried searching if everything is alright, idk what's the problem...

```
C:\Users\PC\Desktop\IGOR\PYTHON\BOTY>git push heroku master

Enumerating objects: 8, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8/8), 2.86 KiB | 1.43 MiB/s, done.
Total 8 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to pomibot.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/pomibot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/pomibot.git'
```

There's the error message in cmd.